# Sorting an object in a <ul> list using values to nest it

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am a bit confused about how to do this sorting task.

I have an array of objects looking like this:

```
{
name : "Another Second level code",
id : "aslc",
parent : "flc"
}
```

And a few more (see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnowqc95/) for the complete code)

Each item has a parent code. I want to create an `<ul>` list where each entry is appended to the entry with their parent code in a nested hierarchical structure.

I started with this

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].parent === "none"){
    $("#firstLevel").append("<li id="+data[i].id +">"+data[i].id+"   </li>");
    firstLevelArray.push(data[i].id);
    }
```

}

And it started working well, creating an initial list of the root entries where the parent is "none".

Then I added to the same loop this structure, trying to append to the master codes, another sublist with the entries that have that master code as parent. This didn´t work. I am saying that if the parent of the entry is found in the array for first level, then that entry should be appended as a list to the entry of the parent...

```
if (firstLevelArray.index(data[i].parent !== -1)) {
    $("'#"+data[i].parent+"'").append("<ul><li id="+data[i].id +">"+data[i].id+"</li></ul>");
    }
```

Although I have done some JS things in the past, I was never really strong in this kind of sorting tasks... is there some way I can achieve this sorting in a simpler way?

[JSFiddle for reference.](https://jsfiddle.net/jnowqc95/)

Comment: You can easily accomplish something like that using `jsTree`

Comment: *"Then I added to the same loop*" - If the original array data is not in any particular order then you need to sort it before you start creating the elements, or use a second loop testing for the elements with parents, otherwise you may be processing some of the child elements before their parent is added to the `firstLevelArray`.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn , that is a point I had not considered

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
(function rec(rdata) {
    if(!rdata.length) return;
    //Get and Remove the first element in the array
    var d = rdata.shift();
    //If is root just appended it to the list
    if(d.parent === 'none') {
         $("#firstLevel").append("<li id="+d.id +">"+d.id+"</li>");
    //If 'sub element' and its parent is rendred just append it to its parent 
    } else if($("#"+d.parent).length > 0 ) {
        if($("#"+d.parent).find("> ul").length === 0) {
            $("#"+d.parent).append("<ul></ul>");
        }
        $("#"+d.parent+" > ul").append("<li id="+d.id +">"+d.id+"   <ul></ul></li>");
    //If is a 'sub element' and its parent not rendred yet just delay
    //the rendering by pushing back the element to data
    }else {    
        //delay
        rdata.push(d);
    }
    //Handle the next subset of data
    rec(rdata);
})(data);
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/q736p99c/

Comment: Thank you. It might be that I end up using the jsTree solution suggested in the comments, but I was very interested on seeing how would it work doing it manually, and your code is very clear and simple to understand.

Comment: Nice solution. If there were an orphaned child element it would try to recurse forever and crash though, wouldn't it?

Comment: You are def right ! I didn't pay attention to that, I was coding like 'must-work-i'm-tired ' ! I will see what I can do ! suggestions are welcome. PS: link fixed